# Unable to open file via PHP from HTML page

Tags: php, html

Using the example available at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file.asp , i am learning php with html  .
While trying the provided example to open a file on server using php by hitting an html file on browser  , i see that no file is getting created on the server and it seems php part isn't running there . below is the exact file that i using

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
$file=fopen("welcome.txt","w+");
fwrite($file, "test");
?>

</body>
</html>

Below are apache details,
[root@ learneg]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Feb  7 2012 09:50:11
```

I tried some other codes too , but no success . Please suggest what i could be missing here

Comment: what is the error message you are getting? Did you configure your apache? I also would advice against using w3fools their information on various topic's is dated and they are being very slow on updating it.

Comment: i feel apache and php are good on server , i have also added "AddType application/x-httpd-php .html", Can you share any other example you have

Comment: Your code looks alright and im pretty certain this should work. It must be your apache. I personally like http://www.phptherightway.com/ it's a good reference and pretty solid to start out with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure Apache, so it will parse also .html file. Find section with AddType in httpd.conf and add/uncomment following:

AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html

Answer (score 0):

There should be a simple explanation for this.

You are running it on apache.

```
1) Is php5 installed on apache ?

2) Are you sure the php5 module is enabled ?

3) Does the file have a .php extension ?
```

Apache only parses php when it sees the .php extension.

You could also try this:

```
$file_contents = fopen( "<yourfile>", "r" );
print $file_contents; // This prints the output if it can find it.
fclose($file_contents);
// Write it to a another file.
```